# What's wrong with my 'Bottles of beer on the wall' loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner and I've been stuck on the below for a while; I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I am trying to write a program that prints out the 'Bottles of Beer' song, taking in a number and translating it to the equivalent English word, in each iteration of the song. 
When I try to run the whole program I get the error message:

```
in `english_words': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from 11_classes.rb:83:in `block in print_song'
    from 11_classes.rb:78:in `downto'
    from 11_classes.rb:78:in `print_song'
    from 11_classes.rb:116:in `<main>'
```

But when I test it in irb, the song prints out fine.

Please could someone help explain why this doesn't work when I try to create a new object? I know it's pretty messy and probably quite a long-winded way of doing it but thought trying to do it my own way with what I've learnt so far would be a better way to learn for now.

Thank you!

```
class BeerSong 

 attr_accessor :bottles

 def initialize(bottles)
  bottles = 0 if bottles < 0
  bottles = 99 if bottles > 99
  @bottles = bottles
 end

 @single_nums = { 
  19 => "Nineteen",
  18 => "Eighteen",
  17 => "Seventeen",
  16 => "Sixteen",
  15 => "Fifteen",
  14 => "Fourteen",
  13 => "Thirteen",
  12 => "Twelve",
  11 => "Eleven",
  10 => "Ten",
  9 => "nine",
  8 => "eight",
  7 => "seven",
  6 => "six",
  5 => "five",
  4 => "four",
  3 => "three",
  2 => "two",
  1 => "one",
  0 => "Zero"
  }

 @big_nums = {
  9 => "Ninety",
  8 => "Eighty",
  7 => "Seventy",
  6 => "Sixty",
  5 => "Fifty",
  4 => "Fourty",
  3 => "Thirty",
  2 => "Twenty"
  }


 def print_song
  @bottles.downto 1 do |n|
   if @bottles.zero?
    String.new
   else
    puts """
     #{english_words(n)} #{bottle(n)} of beer on the wall,
     #{english_words(n)} #{bottle(n)} of beer,
     Take one down, pass it around,
     #{english_words(n-1)} #{bottle(n+1)} of beer on the wall.
     """
   end
  end
 end

 def english_words(bottles)
   if bottles <= 19
    @single_nums[bottles].capitalize
   elsif bottles % 10 == 0
    split_number = bottles.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)
    @big_nums[split_number[0]]
   else
    split_number = bottles.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)
    "#{@big_nums[split_number[0]]}-#{@single_nums[split_number[1]]}"
   end
 end

 def bottle(n)
  if n == 1
   'bottle' 
  else 
   'bottles' 
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add what is not working, what the error is you see and what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I have updated my question a bit - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables `@single_nums` and `@big_nums` are defined in terms of an instance and should be set up in initialize.

Move `@single_nums = {...` and `@big_nums = {...` into `initialize` and it should work.

Or you could make them constants: `SINGLE_NUMS = {...`, `BIG_NUMS = {...` and leave them where they are.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to `@single_nums` and `@big_nums` from instance methods. But you declared those in the class context.

Move them to the `initialize` or make them methods like this:

```
def big_nums
  @big_nums ||= {
    ...your values here...
  }
end
```

This uses *memoization* so you do not create the hash over and over again.